# How to use jQuery to access REST API site that returns text/x-json

Tags: jquery, json, api, rest

There is an API webservice provided to us that I need to integrate with our HTML5 website. I have tried using `$.get` or `$.ajax` but there was no luck on getting the data return by the API. The API returns the content-type of  `text/x-json`.

Comment: That is so common that it is very hard to help you. Can you see the data exchange happening, for example in the network tab of a JavaScript debugger? Are you running into the same origin policy trap? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearchitect your application:

Do the AJAX call against your server where you need to add backend code (Java, PHP, whatever) that on your request does the fetching from weather.com. Your AJAX call will then grab the result from your backend and add that information to your frontend.

Comment: thanks @mw. ill just ask permission first if i could create php ( server side coding)  to allow me to access other domain apis. thanks